# JavaScript Help (Loops and Arrays in Particular)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am doing an assignment for a required javascript class and am stuck on a couple of parts specifically. We are supposed to create a guessing game with an array where we prompt the user to guess names and if they match anything in the array to tally it up as points.

Anyway here is the main code, the part that I am stuck on is figuring out how to loop the code so when the user is prompted 3 times for a guess and each guess is taken into account

```
var sportsArray = ["Football","Basketball","Rollerblading","Hiking","Biking","Swimming"];

var name = prompt("Please enter your name.", "Enter Here");

var arrayGuess = prompt("Guess a sport.", "Enter Here");
var counter;
for (counter = 0; counter < sportsArray.length; counter++) {
    if (arrayGuess === "Football"||"Basketball"||"Rollerblading"||"Hiking"||"Biking"||"Swimming"){
        alert("Good Job");
    } else {
        arrayGuess;
    }
}
```

So the goal is to prompt the user to guess a part of the original array and if they do let them know that, but if they don't take points away and make them guess again until they have guessed 3 times.

Anyway if someone could lend a hand it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simultaneously compare one item to a whole bunch of things like this:

```
if (arrayGuess === "Football"||"Basketball"||"Rollerblading"||"Hiking"||"Biking"||"Swimming")
```

Instead, you have to compare it to each individual item:

```
if (arrayGuess === "Football"||
    arrayGuess === "Basketball"||
    arrayGuess === "Rollerblading"||
    arrayGuess === "Hiking"||
    arrayGuess === "Biking"||
    arrayGuess === "Swimming")
```

Or, there are more effective ways to compare to multiple items such as:

```
if (" Football Basketball Rollerblading Hiking Biking Swimming ".indexOf(" " + arrayGuess + " ") !== -1)
```

Or, using an array:

```
if (["Football","Basketball","Rollerblading","Hiking","Biking","Swimming"].indexOf(arrayGuess) !== -1)
```

Or, if this comparison happened a lot, you'd build an object ahead of time and use it for a lookup:

```
var items = {"Football":true,"Basketball":true,"Rollerblading":true,"Hiking":true,"Biking":true,"Swimming":true};

if (items[arrayGuess] === true)
```

---

If you want to compare without regards for proper case, then you can lowercase what the user entered and compare that to lower case test values:

```
var items = {"football":true,"basketball":true,"rollerblading":true,"hiking":true,"biking":true,"swimming":true};

if (items[arrayGuess.toLowerCase()] === true)
```

---

FYI, it's also not clear why you're using a loop here at all.  No loop is needed to prompt once and test against all the possible sports values.

---

If you have to cycle through an array with a loop, then you can do this:

```
var items = ["football","basketball","rollerblading","hiking","biking","swimming"];
var testVal = arrayGuess.toLowerCase();
var match = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (testVal === items[i]) {
        // found a match
        match = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (match !== -1) {
    // items[match] was the match
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Comment: You actually just reminded me of the thing I have been forgetting this entire time, the indexOf method. I knew there was a way to call the objects and what not but I forgot what it was.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, is there a way that I can take what the user entered even if the casing is incorrect, for example if they write a sport name but dont capitalize the first letter?

Comment: @user2926583 - added a comment about your loop.

Comment: A part of the assignment is for us to run through the array using a loop, so I might be taking it a bit farther than I have to.

Comment: @user2926583 - added a loop cycling through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things wrong here, as was already mentioned, your comparison in the if statement needs to reference the variable each time it is compared. But additionally, since you are in a loop based on the length of your sportsArray variable, it would be better to not reference strings at all in the if statement, and instead do something more like the following:

```js
if (arrayGuess === sportsArray[counter]) {
    // Do stuff here
} else {
    // Do other stuff here
}
```

Additionally, your else clause isn't going to behave quite like you are expecting it to. You are going to have to assign a new value to it, probably by way of another call to prompt. As of now you are only referencing the variable, which will do nothing. If you need to take three guesses, I would add an 'else if' clause into the mix where you get a new value for the variable, an let the else clause display a score and break out of the loop.

```js
if (arrayGuess === sportsArray[counter]) {
    // Add to the score
} else if (counter < 2) {
    // We prompted for the first guess before the loop,
    // so take the second and third here
    arrayGuess = prompt("Guess a sport.", "Enter Here");
} else {
    // Display score then break to exit the loop
    break;
}
```